# Transform pandas dataframe to another layout

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  column1  column2  column3
0       A    0.020     0.76
1       B    0.045     1.30
2       C    0.230     0.32
3       D    0.130     0.67
```

I would like to modify this dataframe structure to make it look like this:

```
column1  newCol 
A        column2    0.020
         column3    0.760
B        column2    0.045
         column3    1.300
C        column2    0.230
         column3    0.320
D        column2    0.130
         column3    0.670
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Where `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `newCol` are the names for the columns
A, B, C, D are unique values for rows

My problem is that I don't know how to convert `column1` and `column2` from columns to rows in the new dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `melt` + `set_index` + `sort_index` -

```
df.melt('column1', var_name='newCol')\
  .set_index(['column1', 'newCol'])\
  .sort_index().value

column1  newCol 
A        column2    0.020
         column3    0.760
B        column2    0.045
         column3    1.300
C        column2    0.230
         column3    0.320
D        column2    0.130
         column3    0.670
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Works with `v0.20` and above. For older versions, use `pd.melt` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly. But I have an additional question. Let's assume I have several identical rows in my initial dataframe. Same value for column1, column2 and column3. I could use .drop_duplicates for the whole dataframe before applying your solution, but I was wondering if you could integrate that somehow in your code to do it differently.

Comment: @user9160422 Good question. I'd say the most efficient thing to do would be getting rid of duplicates _first_. `df.drop_duplicates().melt('column1', var_name='newCol').set_index(['column1', 'newCol']).sort_index().value`. Reshaping operations such as stack and melt are expensive, so the lesser the data being passed to these functions, the better.

Comment: Sorry, clicked twice by mistake:)

Answer (score 2):

Set `column1` as index, stack, and rename the index columns:

```
>>> res = df.set_index('column1').stack()
>>> res.index.names = ['column1', 'newCol']
>>> res

column1  newCol 
A        column2    0.020
         column3    0.760
B        column2    0.045
         column3    1.300
C        column2    0.230
         column3    0.320
D        column2    0.130
         column3    0.670
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked as well. However, I would have wanted newCol to be placed as column header for colum2, column3, not the values.

Comment: OK. I though you wanted  dataframe as result. Update my answer to get a series.